# Is there a list of cordova plugins that use UIWebView API?

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I had no luck in finding the list myself.

---

If anyone knows a faster way to find out if specific cordova plugin references UIWebView instead of manually searching source code for API calls it would be nice to share with us.

Answer (score 6):

No such list exists.

You don't need to manually search source code. In the root of your project type:

```
grep -lr "UIWebView" *
```

You will likely have results with documentation references, but it shouldn't be too hard to see the plugin source code files (.m/.h) that are referencing it.